# Android GCM - New Google API Console

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I use GCM a long time but with the new Google Console Interface, the behaviour is a little different.

You have to create the Project and get the Project ID. This is the GCM Sender ID. That´s ok.

But after that you have to create the App.

The GCM documentation says to create an App and click "Android > Accessing APIs directly from Android".

Docs here: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html.

This should be the API KEY to send messages in the server, but it doesn´t work.

But if I create a Web App and get the "> Server Key > API Key" it works!

This makes sense? thank you

Answer (score 1):

I followed the exact steps specified by Android and it worked exactly as they say it should.

> To obtain an API key:
>
> ```
> 1. In the sidebar on the left, select APIs & auth > Registered apps.
> 2. Click Register app.
> 3. In the Name field, type your app's name.
> 4. Click Android > Accessing APIs directly from Android.
> 5. Under Android identification, type the package name for your app.
> 6. Enter an SHA1 fingerprint. To get this value, follow the instructions in the
>    console help.
> 7. Click Register.
> 8 .In the new page, open the Android Key section and copy the API key. You will need
>    the API key later on to perform authentication in your application server.
> ```

And I got the SHA1 fingerprint with the command:

> keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\myusername\.android\debug.keystore -list -v

(and password `android`)

Comment: Yes, I followed this steps two. But as I said, it did not work. But if I create the key as a Web Application, and get the SERVER KEY it works.

Comment: I can´t send the message in the server, it says invalid key.